# Django - convert queryset to html elements

Tags: python, django, bokeh

Im using Bokeh library for visualizing data. Embeding Bokeh charts into web apps is possible via exporting <script>  and <div> (inserting them in this comment as text also required using special strings - &lt and &gt) html components of visualization and inserting them in html template.

I have these components in Django database.

How to insert them into templates, so they will be treated as html elements? Now I get rendered everything as plain text, because output to template automatically converts tags <,> to &lt and &gt.

Thank you for help!

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the html in a model field (django database) then in your view, you'd get them using a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/), passing the results to the context which is [then passed to the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) to be rendered.

If you want to provide some more detail as to the model they are in I can provide a little more concrete advice.

Comment: Or for more complete description https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping

Comment: Also have the option to mark content as safe in the view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe